C# array of string not nullable but init with null string[] arrayOfString = new string[2];
Working with VS2022 and .NET 8 with <Nullable>Enabled</Nullable> for my project.
I encounter null pointer exception at run time with the following code:
string[] arrayOfString = new string[2];
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(',', arrayOfString.Select(s => s ?? "null")))
arrayOfString[0].ToString();

The array is created with 2 string where the default value for string which is null.
I fixed the issue with the following initialization:
string?[] arrayOfString = new string[2];

However, I was expecting a warning at compile time (an error at compilation in my case as I set <TreatWarningsAsErrors>True</TreatWarningsAsErrors>) with Nullable enabled?
Is it an expected behavior or a bug?

Side note: s => s ?? null is redundant and can be dropped: "if s is null, let it be null"

Cannot reproduce

"I was expecting a compilation error" Nullable violations cause warning, not errors. But  i agree that there could be a warning.

"Arrays and structs that contain reference types are known pitfalls in nullable references and the static analysis that determines null safety. In both situations, a non-nullable reference might be initialized to null, without generating warnings." from docu here

@Ralf: "known pitfalls in nullable references and the static analysis that determines null safety" could also be called "known bugs". It was just too much effort to implement it i would say.

@TimSchmelter Yes I'm with you on that. As there are so many ways to manipulate an array they presumably could only decide between actually warn almost always (with many false positives) and warn never and choose the later.

@DmitryBychenko Thanks for your reply I updated my post ; s => s ?? "null" to highlight null value in String.Join as otherwise they lead to String.Empty

@TimSchmelter Thanks it should be indeed a warning and I made confusion, as I setup my project to TreatWarningsAsErrors which I think is a good practice

@gbs69: Basically you would end up with a warning almost any time you initialized an array with a non-nullable reference type. I trust that the C# team evaluated various options, and picked one which is at least reasonable.

@JonSkeet so we should not initialized an array without using nullable reference type, to get the Nullable mode reliable.
We worked for years without Nullable check at compile time and are used to handle it properly.
Adding warnings for many cases but not all, will encourage developers to rely on warnings and stop writing checks if no warning, I found that dangerous.

I disagree - I think you're throwing the baby out with the bathwater. But it's a matter of opinion, basically. (This isn't the only way of "tricking" the compiler around nullable reference types. I think MS has been reasonably clear that a warning-free build is not a guarantee that you'll never run into nullable reference issues.)

NRT is a gimmick feature which is imprecise at best, not infallible, comes with a kill switch ! and doesn't really work at runtime. Add explicit null checks if it worries you rather than relying on a half-baked compromise.

@mjwills @sweeper Thanks. Indeed there was a glitch so I edited my intial post to replace:
Before:
arrayOfString.ToString();
After:
arrayOfString[0].ToString();
